# With Regards to the Security Update

Tags: discussion, blog, security

I'm not really sure what's the right avenue to do this so I'll try meta. I promise to take it well if this gets closed or downvoted :]

I just wanted to say **thank you** for the way you're handling the [security issue](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/05/16/security-update/?cb=1). It is refreshing given what we've been used to in the tech industry and in particular I am thankful for:

- The fast disclosure.
- The fact we're being updated even though only a small amount of users are impacted.
- The fact it was discovered quickly.
- The fact Stack Overflow are going to work with a third-party forensics firm in addition to their own engineering.
- The fact it's being taken seriously.

I feel safe saying this since I have no affiliation with anyone in Stack Overflow - I just wanted to say thank you for the professional response. It's not obvious and I realize it would have been easier to do the irresponsible thing and not disclose things until later. As a user this increases my confidence in the company.

Note: Please do not discuss the actual details of the security incident here - this post is "meta" in that it's about how it is handled and not the incident itself.

Comment: Yeh, a sharp contrast to organisations like Uber.

Comment: Honestly, it's just nice to have a question that's not complaining :D We could have a new tag `dodo` for questions like these.

Comment: How much you wanna bet at least some of the code used to hack Stack Overflow came from Stack Overflow?

Comment: Amen. It's never good to have something like this happen, but I can't imagine a more reassuring response than we've seen here. I hadn't heard of their new VP of Engineering Mary Ferguson until now, so this is making a very good first impression.

Comment: Very much agree. I'd love to see a more extensive postmortem down the road, just out of personal interest, but I can fully understand if that doesn't come since there might be details that they'd rather not disclose.

Comment: They will also notify all the 250 users who were affected by the breach. Other companies should learn from SO about how to react to a breach. Most importantly they are updating us via the blog. Instead of a press conference that might shake the site users

Comment: I was wondering what you are talking about, until I saw on the right side of my screen "Security Update" and "Update to Security Incident [May 17, 2019]" links. I suspect in a bit of time those will no longer be visible and this post then doesn't reference what it is really talking about.

Comment: @TT. but the blog post will remain so the OP should give a link to the blogs in their question.

Comment: @window.document Hence my comment, but didn't want to make the decision to edit in the links :-)

Comment: @TT. I edited the question to include a link to the blog. That blog has a link to the second blog. It's a good idea to link these things, as they get lost when people read a question down the track.

Comment: I would much rather know the full extent and know what they're doing to fix it then anything else. Everyone is vulnerable to getting pwned, what matters is that you need to have confidence that they'll tell you when it happens.

Comment: TBH, for quite a while I interpreted a blog post about "Security Update" as something about them deploying a software update. As such, I didn't really feel any need to read it. Only the second post made it fairly obvious that it was an announcement of a security breach. IMHO this should have been much more obvious, with unambiguous title. (Probably sooner too, 4 business days to basically say "There was a breach last Saturday and we'll keep you posted" isn't exactly fast.)

Comment: Not to be a party pooper but the non-free services hosted by SO are probably a much stronger motivator than SO free.

Comment: @AndrasDeak "Free" only if you consider all the time and effort the countless volunteers spent to make the site what it is today to have no value whatsoever. Doubt they'd be selling much if that didn't exist in the first place. But I get what you mean. Given that they couldn't be bothered to post anything on this question in 5 days says enough. :(

Answer (score 45):

This is not an official answer, but rather to link the poignant information here to ensure it's visible to future readers.

The initial [Security Update](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/05/16/security-update/) was posted on May 16, 2019 by the VP of Engineering at Stack Overflow, [Mary Ferguson](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/maryferguson/). This blog informed us there was a recent security breach:

> We have confirmed that some level of production access was gained on May 11. We discovered and investigated the extent of the access and are addressing all known vulnerabilities. We have not identified any breach of customer or user data. Our customers’ and users’ security is of the utmost importance to us.

There was a subsequent and prompt [Update to Security Incident [May 17, 2019]](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/05/17/update-to-security-incident-may-17-2019/)

250 users had their data accessed and were to be personally informed. The remainder of the site is intact and the vulnerabilities fixed.  She continues to explain that the site has a separation of concerns helping to contain possible security breaches and limit the extent of the damage.

> - Terminating the unauthorized access to the system
> - Conducting an extensive and detailed audit of all logs and databases that we maintain, allowing us to trace the steps and actions that were taken
> - Remediating the original issues that allowed the unauthorized access and escalation, as well as any other potential vectors that we have found during the investigation
> - Issuing a public statement proactively
> - Engaging a third party forensics and incident response firm to assist us with both remediation and learnings
> - Taking precautionary measures such as cycling secrets, resetting company passwords, and evaluating systems and security levels

There will be further updates.

An exemplar of how security breaches need to be handled publicly. It would do well for all organisations to follow such protocol.

Comment: I'll update this answer when we are given more information.

Comment: Is it known if all the 250 affected users have been notified? Until then, we could all be expecting to be notified.

Comment: It was less than 250 and all were notified today - we'll update the post tomorrow (with a date) so it indicates this.

Comment: @NickCraver feel free to make this answer a community wiki

Comment: @NickCraver , Would like to know if there is Any updates on this, If possible, i am curious to know what was the bug and how it was fixed, this may help all developers to be vigilant and avoid these types of bugs while building software.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Any idea when those updates might be coming? Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

I do have a minor quibble with this (and I do mean minor), but it does need saying

> Security Update

If someone were to ask a question entitled that anywhere on SO/SE, it would be edited or closed. It tells you *nothing* about the substance of the post. That's a standard we uphold around here. Often, the SO blog talks about [mundane things](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/04/17/qa-alynes-cto-on-enabling-innovation-in-regulatory-technology/). Maybe SO released some security improvement. Maybe this is just a "We're committed to your security!" rah-rah post. Instead, you click it and get

> Over the weekend, there was an attack on Stack Overflow.

I don't get why it was so vague. Call it `Security Breach` or `We're looking into an intrusion on the SO network`. Something that says "Hey, we had a problem but we're on it!" and not "Here's the weather for Stack Overflow"

That having been said, I cannot underscore how good it was to see a quick admission. I don't know that Equifax ever sent me any notices about [that epic failure they had](https://www.ftc.gov/equifax-data-breach). I'd just like it to be clearer next time.

Comment: It also doesn't mention when SO discovered the attack, which is a key detail.