# Will there be any further updates on the security incident of May 5, 2019?

Tags: support, security, privacy

Stack Overflow had a security incident back in May, in which a small amount of user data was compromised. [This](https://techcrunch.com/2019/05/17/stack-overflow-user-data-exposed/) [received](https://www.zdnet.com/article/stack-overflow-says-hackers-breached-production-systems/) [a lot](https://duo.com/decipher/stack-overflow-updates-breach-advisory-with-more-details) [of attention](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19941797), and the company did a great job communicating their initial investigation to the community and affected users. As a reminder:

- May 5, 2019: Vulnerability introduced. Dev tier compromise by attacker.
- May 11, 2019: The attacker escalates to a prod account, but is [quickly noticed by a diligent user](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=7710008#7710008), allowing staff to cut him off.
- May 16, 2019: [Security Update](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/05/16/security-update/) posted to blog
- May 17, 2019: [Update to Security Incident](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/05/17/update-to-security-incident-may-17-2019/) posted to blog
- May 23, 2019: All compromised users individually contacted. Blog post updated.

This was a [very encouraging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385153/with-regards-to-the-security-update/) initial response. I was looking forward to seeing the next post, since the last one said:

> We will provide more public information after our investigation cycle concludes.

A top comment on Hacker News echoed my feelings:

> I expect the next (or perhaps the 4th) post will be a fuller post-mortem from after the incident. This series of disclosures has given me more confidence in Stack Overflow than I had before!

However, it's now been 6-8 weeks since the last update and I'm beginning to wonder if we misunderstood.

Is the investigation still ongoing? If not, is the company planning to give a further update on the security incident, such as a more-detailed postmortem with explanation of how the pivot from dev to prod was possible? Or was the edit with the number of affected users the end of the "more public information" that the community should expect?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Thanks for your interest.

While we haven’t found any more compromised users or data, our investigation is still ongoing. Unfortunately, these things can take considerable time. We still plan to post a final update when our investigation concludes.

Comment:  totally fair, these things can definitely take a while, just wanted to confirm that it was coming eventually.